# Good project with spring-mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Please advise me a project where I can see how to use Spring MVC and Hibernate together in the right way. I'm new to these frameworks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Appfuse has a Maven archetype for this stack.
Strongly suggest you have a peak.
Alternatively the book Spring in Action was a great resource for me in learning spring and hibernate/spring interaction - use Annotation driven transaction management as well and you have a really great start.

see here: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Using+Spring+MVC
appfuse-basic-spring is the basic project archetype.

Using maven modules is a better practice. ie) 
appfuse-modular-spring

### If you install m2e (maven 2 eclipse plugin) creating a new maven project will allow you to select the archetype.

better answer:

If I was going to recommend HOW to learn these technologies, I would say learn how to build a hibernate/maven/xml project first by following this: 
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/

Then learn how to use spring for dependency injection with maven/hibernate and xml:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/
Take special note of layering of the bo/dao pattern and how you use interfaces but wire in implementations with spring di - this is crucial for writing quality code

Next check hibernate annotations and annotation driven transactions:
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config.html
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config-code-example.html
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-hibernate-annonation-mysql-example/

Finally, you can learn your mvc framework of choice. I actually recommend struts2 but it won't matter much. use spring DI by implementing interfaces and wiring implementations at runtime for you actions/controller. If you don't understand this how, you will after the hibernate/spring tutorials. Spring in action will be a good reference to keep on your desk but will take a few weeks to digest as you learn. Good luck! You can do it - I did and am now working as a java dev!

Comment: By the way, since my original post I've explored spring MVC and I think it may be better for restful webservices in its recent incarnations (less code). Struts2 is still awesome if you need to conquer tricky tasks like strange cross cutting concerns in security with the interceptor pattern. Spring has AOP which is a near equivalent but requires you to focus on a more broad concept (AOP) when you're trying to get stuff done. I've moved over to scala akka and play for projects for fun and would recommend them if you're good with java core.

Answer (score 2):

- the [petclinic app](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) includes these, and many more things
- [spring-roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) can create a skeleton project using these technologies for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Spring MVC and Hibernate, I advice you to follow the [Spring MVC step by step guide](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/). The only problem with this is the version, the guide uses version 2.5 and the current release is 3.1.x, but it's a very good starting point to accumulate knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring MVC quickstart archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) provide simple spring-mvc and hibernate configuration.